# Why does the value of one variable seem to override another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some simple code that finds the value of m by doing y2-y1/x2-x1. However, for some reason the value of `x1` is overridden by `x2`. This is strange as the same does not occur for `y1` and `y2`.

Here is the code:

```
def asker():
    global y2
    global y1
    global x1
    global x2
    y2 = float(input("What's your y2 value?:"))
    y1 = float(input("What is your y1 value?"))
    x2 = float(input("What is your x2 value?:"))
    x1 = float(input("What is your x1 value?:"))

#Lots of coding until:

 elif equation == 'point':
        while True:
             slope = input("Do you need to find slope? Type 'yes' or 'no'.")
             if slope == 'yes':
                asker()
                m = y2-y1/x2-x1
                stringer()
                break
             elif slope == 'no':
                m = input("What is the slope?")
                y1 = float(input("What is your y1 value?"))
                x1 = float(input("What is your x1 value?:"))
                break
             else:
                print("Must enter in either 'yes' or 'no'")
                continue

        m,y1,x1 = str(m),str(y1),str(x1)

        print("Your equation is: y - {} = {}(x - {})".format(y1,m,x1))
```

I printed out all values within the `if slope == 'yes'` section and all values were correct. I did the same outside the if/elif/else statement and all the previous values were carried over except for some reason x2 overrides x1.

Here's a link to my entire file if you need it: https://repl.it/repls/KeyScientificGraduate

Comment: You don't need to use `str()` before calling `format()`.

Comment: You know that your formula is equivalent to `y2 - (y1/x2) - x1`, not `(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)`, right?

Comment: for slope? @Barmar

Comment: In the statement `m = y2-y1/x2-x1`. Look up operator precedence.

Comment: The problem is in the `stringer()` function, which you didn't put in the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that my m formula was wrong, I didn't even realize it @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the left hand side of your assignment in the stringer() function.

```
y1,x1,y2,x1,m = str(y1),str(x1),str(y2),str(x2),str(m)
```

It looks like you have x1 being assigned twice from the unpacked tuple.

This is an illustration of why it's bad to use globals (most of the time). It's hard to tell where things are getting updated.

Comment: Where do you see the `stringer()` function?

Comment: @Barmar in the linked file.

Comment: And this function is totally unnecessary in the first place, since `format()` doesn't need strings.

Answer (score 1):

First, as many people have already mentioned, you do not need a `stringer()` function since `.format` takes care of variable types for you.

Second, I think you should consider the scope of your variables more carefully. While it may appear to be convenient to just use global variables, it could often lead to unintended errors (like variable override) if you are not very familiar with pythonic codes.

I suggest that you take the inputs given by the user and store them in local variables to pass around the functions as arguments.